# Return a formatted array of events

Tags: angularjs, laravel-5

I'm trying to integrate [Angular Bootstrap Calendar](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar) to my Laravel 5 project. Right now, the calendar works using the provided pre-populated demo list of events.

```
vm.events = [
  {
    title: 'An event',
    type: 'warning',
    startsAt: moment().startOf('week').subtract(2, 'days').add(8, 'hours').toDate(),
    endsAt: moment().startOf('week').add(1, 'week').add(9, 'hours').toDate(),
    draggable: true,
    resizable: true
  }, {
    title: 'Event 2',
    type: 'info',
    startsAt: moment().subtract(1, 'day').toDate(),
    endsAt: moment().add(5, 'days').toDate(),
    draggable: true,
    resizable: true
  }, {
    title: 'This is a really long event title that occurs on every year',
    type: 'important',
    startsAt: moment().startOf('day').add(7, 'hours').toDate(),
    endsAt: moment().startOf('day').add(19, 'hours').toDate(),
    recursOn: 'year',
    draggable: true,
    resizable: true
  }
];
```

I would like to retrieve and format the events from my database like the example above, but I'm not sure how to tackle this from my controller.

On the Angular Calendar side, I've read that I can use the angular $http service to load the events, like this:

```
$http.get('/events').success(function(events) {
    //TODO - format your array of events to match the format described in the docs
    $scope.events = events; //Once formatted correctly add them to the scope variable and the calendar will update
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: One option is to return the formatted JSON from the backend. Then "$scope.events = $events" will be enough. If it's not possible, you need to process the response in the success callback, but how to do this depends on the structure of your API's response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you would want to do is create a service that takes care of all the HTTP request/response handling and have your controller consume it to get/save/update data. Something like:

```
// assuming that you have a REST service endpoint at /events


// create your service that will handle all HTTP interaction for the events resource
app.factory('EventsService', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        getAll: function() {
            // fetch all events asynchronously
            return $http.get('/events').success(function(response) {
                var events = response.data;

                // if you need to do any pre-processing of the events first, do it here

                // pass  your events to the next function in the promise chain.
                return events;
            }, function(err) {
                // handle errors here

                // pass your error object down the chain in case other error callbacks are added later on to the promise.
                return err;
            });
        }
    };
}]);

app.controller('YourController', ['$scope', 'EventsService', function($scope, EventsService) {
    // call the asynchronous service method and add  your promise success callback that returns your array of events to be bound to your context.
    EventsService.getAll().then(function(evts) {
        $scope.events = evts;
    }, function(err) {
        // do any additional error handling here
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you help. I'm new to Laravel and Angular, so I am going to re-read that a couple of times to understand. I don't actually have an endpoint at /events, this is also something I'll have to create when I get what I have to return exactly, data formatted in JSON?

Comment: Not a problem, take  your time and let us know if you have additional questions. I am fairly familiar with building APIs with Laravel also, so I may be able to answer questions there as well. If you aren't already familiar with the Laracast series, I would highly recommend them for getting ramped up in Laravel, all at a very inexpensive monthly rate. I would recommend this series for what you are doing: https://laracasts.com/series/incremental-api-development

Comment: Btw, other than being a customer myself I have no affiliation with Laracasts.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. Laracast is great, I've listened to the laravel fundamental series, it's great. I'm going to have to check this series out too. Thanks